# Provide different opacity in different part for same image

Tags: css, image, opacity

I have an `image`. And i have to provide different level of `opacity` in different part for the same image.The part of image can be our choice. Look at the image and it tells more.

[image]

**NOTE:** This is a sample image only used to show an example.

Is this possible??

Comment: It is only possible if you set the different levels of opacity in the source image itself. use a .png file. That or you can slice it up and "stitch" it together by lining up elements next to each other and controlling opacity that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to provide a prepared image for this usecase. Nontheless, here is one possiblilty with plain CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sur7D/1/

CSS:

```
.image1
{
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size:contain;
}

.split-image
{
    height: 200px;
}

.split-image > div
{
    height: inherit;
    width: 33.333%;
    float:left;
    transform: skewX(-25deg)
}

.split-image > div:nth-child(1){
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.split-image > div:nth-child(2){
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.split-image > div:nth-child(3){
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="split-image">
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="image1"></div>
</div>
```